# Something like get_cookie_name in Flask's SessionInterface?

Tags: flask, flask-login

I have a need to use different sessions depending on the subpath of the url that the user is visiting in my Flask application

For example I want a user visiting www.example.com to have session based on a cookie named "root_cookie" but a user visiting www.example.com/subpath should have a session based on a cookie named "subpath_cookie"

For me this mainly has to do with Flask-Login and how I'd like to have different independent logged in sessions depending on the subpath in which the user logged in.

Now, Flask's [`session_interface`](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/1.0/api/#flask.Flask.session_interface) attribute allows you to set a custom class which you can subclass from [`SessionInterface`](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/1.0/api/#flask.sessions.SessionInterface).
It's really nice that you can override almost anything in `SessionInterface` including the cookie's domain ([`get_cookie_domain()`](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/1.0/api/#flask.sessions.SessionInterface.get_cookie_domain)) and the cookie's path ([`get_cookie_path()`](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/1.0/api/#flask.sessions.SessionInterface.get_cookie_path)).

One thing that is missing for me is a function that could be named `get_cookie_name()` which would be helpful to override for the reasons stated above.

I realise that maybe I can just override `get_cookie_path()` to set a different cookie per subpath. The problem comes in in the root url. If I set the cookie's path to '/' it'll also come into effect in subpaths, including those for which I want to use a different session. So setting a different cookie name if it's the root url, would solve the problem. But I can't because `get_cookie_name()` doesn't exist.

Is there any mechanism in Flask that I'm missing that can help with this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After not being satisfied with having to override `save_session()` to solve my problem, I submitted a [pull request](https://github.com/pallets/flask/pull/3369) to create a `get_cookie_name()` method in the Flask project which was merged in to the master branch. From version 2.0.0 of Flask one will be able to use this new functionality as per the docs: https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/master/api/#flask.sessions.SessionInterface.get_cookie_name

Answer (score 0):

You can check out the [Response.set_cookie()](https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/1.1.x/api/#flask.Response.set_cookie) method where you can pass in your cookie name. Example can be found in  Flask's *SecureCookieSessionInterface*:

```
response.set_cookie(
    app.session_cookie_name, # Substitute this with desired name.
    val,
    expires=expires,
    httponly=httponly,
    domain=domain,
    path=path,
    secure=secure,
    samesite=samesite
)
```

Since you want to set the name based on your endpoint, you may require the request object which is available to you as per documentation:

> This is called for actual sessions returned by open_session() at the end of the request. This is still called during a request context so if you absolutely need access to the request you can do that.

Taken from [SessionInterface.save_session()](https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/1.1.x/api/#flask.sessions.SessionInterface.save_session).

Comment: Are you saying that I should override the save_session() method? Sounds fine, but then my next question is: if there already exists get_cookie_secure(), get_cookie_samesite(), get_expiration_time() method, why didn't the Flask developers also just make a get_cookie_name() function too?

Comment: I would say overriding the save_session() would be the most straightforward way.
Those methods are all getters (hence "get" in their names) so a get_cookie_name() wouldn't really help your case as it wouldn't set the name of the cookie but rather just return it. I also can't think of a sensible way to even implement the get_cookie_name() method since session and cookie are usually not the same thing so this method shouldn't be a part of a session object, in my opinion.

Comment: I guess I was just following on from the fact that Flask's SessionInterface has get_cookie_domain(), get_cookie_path(), get_cookie_secure(), get_cookie_samesite(). By extension it would make sense to have a get_cookie_name().